# Moving average around the year in a loop

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series and I calculated the rolling means `rollmean(df,3,na.pad=TRUE)` but because of the way it is calculated I get the first and last day `NA` values, and when I plot it I have a gap. Is it possible to calculate rolling means in a loop? e.g. using the last day of the year to calculate the first day and the same way around?

[image]

```
df<- read.csv("https://github.com/gonzalodqa/timeseries/sap_rollmean.csv")
```

I was thinking of adding rows with those values but I am afraid that might mess my date columns and the graph overall

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: try using `rollmean(df,3,na.pad=TRUE, align = "right")`. Then the NA's are on the left where they should be.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have 2 NA, NA in the first 2 days so I still have a gap. It wouldn't be a problem if my figure was from Jan-Dec, but i is from Oct-Sep.

Comment: Is it possible to force ggplot to close the gap graphically?  ````ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=rollmean)+geom_line()````

Comment: can you create a mwe? And where the rolmean is messing up your data. Because we are jumping in the middle of your data, without seeing / knowing why you use the rollmean, with a center, which column you base the rolmean on and what your expected output is. Because the graph as it is now, doesn't show me what you are missing.